# CodeIgniter Pagination Multiple Table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have school work on databases and pagination, The task is, to show data on selected table.

For example when we select  "**table_data1**"  the browser will display  data from "**table_data1**" and show it as a pagination page,

I found a tutorial about pagination, then I modified the code, the result is, yes it shows 5 of the first page record of data, but the pagination of the next page is not shown, when I choose next page.

this my model,**$tabel** is to chose which of **table_data$** to run query.

```
class Page_model  extends CI_Model{

function join_data($limit, $start,$table)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->from('tbl_param');
    $this->db->join('tbl_data' . $table, 'tbl_data' . $table .'.id  =  tbl_param.child_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('table_limit' . $table, 'table_limit' . $table .'.id  =  tbl_param.child_id', 'left');
    $query4 = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    return $query4->result();
}
}
```

this my controller ,**$tabel** is to chose which of **table_data$** to show

```
class Page extends CI_Controller{

function page($table)
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination'); 
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/page/'.$table.'/';            
        $config['total_rows'] = 20;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
       
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
       
        $data['table'] = $this->page_model->join_data($config["per_page"], $page,$table);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('v_page', $data);
    }
}
```

and the view

```
 <?php foreach($table as $tables){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $tables->id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tables->param;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tables->data;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tables->alarm;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } 
        echo $links;
        ?>
```

I hope there someone help me or explain, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your `$config['base_url']` and `$page`

your `$config['base_url']` should be `base_url().'index.php/page/page/'.$table;`

note the second `page`, the method you need to call inside your `page` controller.

your `$page` should be `$page = $this->uri->segment(4);`

Comment: Ok , after i change my : base_url().'index.php/page/page'.$table.'/page/'; it show data per page (pagination works) , but after end of page "last" , the links for   firts page not show, the links stil show like this  " 1 2 3 > last"

Comment: how many total records and how many records per page you show?